# How to get the exact metadata location of any hdfs data?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, metadata

How can the exact hdfs metadata location can be found out?As we know that Namenode has the information regarding the datanode and all.burt i want to have the exact meta data file where physically the information regarding the data is present from where namenode extract the information.

Comment: Why?...........

Comment: I just want to see how the metadata is stored i mean in which and all.i cant get the concept of edit logs and fimage